# Catching Get-EventLog errors

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a simple script to parse some event logs but I need to silence some errors for times when there are no results, or if the instanceid is invalid:

```
PS C:\> get-eventlog Application -instanceid 1111

Get-EventLog : No matches found
At line:1 char:13
  + get-eventlog <<<<  Application -instanceid 1111
      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-EventLog], ArgumentException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetEventLogNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

I can do that and silence it, but that would also silence other errors:

```
PS C:\> try { get-eventlog Application -instanceid 1111 -erroraction stop } catch { }
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
PS C:\> try { get-eventlog Application -instanceid 1111 -erroraction stop } catch [ObjectNotFound] { }

Unable to find type [ObjectNotFound]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:91
  + try { get-eventlog Application -instanceid 1111 -erroraction stop } catch [ObjectNotFound] <<<< { }
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ObjectNotFound:String) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and check your `$error` variable after it,

```
$error[0]
```

It will always contains the last error object.

Answer (score 2):

By no means the only option but you could try something like this:

```
$result = get-eventlog Application -instanceid 1111 -erroraction silentlycontinue
if($result){
    Write-Host "Found some."
} else{
    Write-Host "wah wah wah waaaah... you know like the trombone sound"
}
```

Once again I dont read a post fully. To make better on my answer I offer up this which might help your `try` block woes

```
try {
    get-eventlog Application -instanceid 1111 -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch [Exception]{
    $theError = $_
    Switch($theError .Exception.GetType().FullName){
        System.InvalidOperationException{Write-Host "This happened: $($theError.Exception.Message)"}
        System.ArgumentException {Write-Host "This happened: $($theError.Exception.Message)"}
        default{"Something else happened: $($theError.Exception.GetType().FullName)"}
    }
}
```

Use `-Stop` to create a terminating error. Capture any exceptions and put the error object into variable so it can be used in other scopes later. Get the exception name and use a switch statement on it to determine appropriate action. In your case of "No matches found" that throws a `[System.ArgumentException]` which you can tell from looking at the value of `$_.Exception.GetType().FullName`. Capture the specific errors in the switch statement and if you have not already caught a particular exception before you can see the details in `default`.

For what its worth `[System.InvalidOperationException]` occurred when I replaced "Application" in the cmdlet call to "Fizgig"

Comment: The problem is I want other errors to show, for example if the logfile is wrong or the connection could not be made. I just want to silence invalid instanceid and empty results.

Answer (score 1):

you should try following syntax to get your error while not stopping script execution :

```
    try
    {
        # check for eventLog
        Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -InstanceId 1111 -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        # send error as ID
        Write-Warning "Error -Message $($_.Exception.Message) -Line $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber) -Time $(Get-Date -Format 'HH.mm.ss.fff')"
    }
```